# Error in writing text file

Tags: php

I'm beginner in PHP. I want to write some numbers in the .txt file. I wrote this code in phpstorm program:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$l=5;
$a = fopen("./mmm.txt", "w");
for ($m = 1;$m <=3 ; $m++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 2 ^ $m; $j++) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $l - $m; $i++) {
            fwrite($a,$j * 2 ^ ($i - 1));
        }
    }
}
fclose($a);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code in Mozilla Firefox, I face with these errors:
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in... or Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in...

and the size of mmm.txt file is approximately 138000 KB.
what is wrong?

Comment: check these in your php.ini max_execution_time AND
memory_limit , increase them

Comment: @ArditMeti, Time and space needed for my code are not large, I don't know why this error occurred.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print into the file? If you look at this it's running many thousand iterations.

Comment: You do realise that `^` in PHP Is a bitwise operator, not the power operator; `$j <= pow(2, $m)` or `$j <= 2 ** $m` and `pow($j * 2, ($i - 1));` or `($j * 2) ** ($i - 1);` (depending on your version of PHP)

Comment: Dear @MarkBaker, Yes, thanks.